# xarray: reshape data, split dimension

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-xarray

I have a Dataset in `xarray` with the following dimensions:

```
Dimensions:      (subject: 30, session: 5, time: 45000)
Coordinates:
  * subject      (subject) object '110' '112' '114' '117' ...
  * session      (session) object 'week1' 'week2' 'week3' ...
  * time         (time) timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00 00:00:00.040000 ...
```

I want to split each trial (subject/session combo) into smaller time segments, for example into 3 segments of 15000 values each, The resulting dimensions may look as follows:

```
(subject: 30, session: 5, segment: 3, time: 15000)
```

I've searched and tried a lot of things but have not succeeded, how can this be done?

One of the things that I've been trying, that seems to be close, is creating a new MultiIndex and unstacking it.

```
segment_data = np.repeat(range(3),len(ds.time)//3)
segment = xr.Variable(dims='time',data=segment_data)
newtime_data = np.tile(ds.time[:len(ds.time)//3],3)
newtime = xr.Variable(dims='time',data=newtime_data)
dsr = ds.assign_coords(segment=segment,newtime=newtime)
dsr = dsr.set_index(segment='segment',newtime='newtime')
dsr = dsr.stack(fragment=['segment','newtime'])
```

However that last line takes a huge amount of memory and seems to create a dimension `fragment: len(ds.time)**2`, which doesn't seem right. I'm also no sure what I would have to do after this (`unstack('fragment')`?).

edit: Some more attempts have brought me here:

```
x = np.repeat(range(3),15000)
y = np.tile(ds.time[:len(ds.time)//3],3)
dsr = (ds.assign_coords(segment=x,time2=y)
      .set_index(fragment=['segment','time2'])
      .unstack('fragment'))
```

Which gives this:

```
(subject: 30, segment: 3, session: 5, time: 45000, time2: 15000)
```

This seems close but it's not quite there since every `time2` point now has 45000 values while it should be a single value:

```
dsr.isel(subject=0,segment=0,session=0,time2=0)
# (time: 45000)
```

edit: I finally found a way to do it, see my answer. Futher suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First make sure you have the labels for the two new dimensions. In this case as follows:

```
x = range(3) # 3 segments
y = ds.time[:len(ds.time)//3] # the first 1/3rd of the time labels
```

Then create a `pandas` MultiIndex from these labels*.

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((x,y),names=('segment','new_time'))
```

Finally, replace the `time` index in the Dataset by this new index, and then unstack its levels to create the two required dimensions.

```
dsr = ds.assign(time=ind).unstack('time')
```

You may want to use `rename` to rename the new dimension:

```
dsr = dsr.rename({'new_time':'time'})
```

Resulting dimensions:

```
(subject: 30, segment: 3, session: 5, time: 15000)
```

The only thing that's off now is the order of the dimensions (ideally `segment` and `session`  should be swapped). I thought `transpose` would help here but ["although the order of dimensions on each array will change, the dataset dimensions themselves will remain in fixed (sorted) order."](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.transpose.html) ** So I'll probably live with it like this.

<sub>* Note you won't be able to use the name of the dimension you want to split, so we have `'new_time'` here. An unnecessary limitation of `assign`?</sub>

<sub>** Another limitation that I can't explain.</sub>

Comment: I see the problem that creating the MultiIndex says unhashable type: 'DataArray' - for `y`. Needs conversion to numpy array there to proceed.